# Set HSTS Header on WebSphere Application Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, hsts

An application can use HSTS by setting the Strict-Transport-Security header with the appropriate values. 
Once a browser that supports HSTS receives this header, it will force all future connections to that domain to take place over  or  ridirect to HTTPS.

I've read on this site http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/questions.html#HSTS and it mention that WebSphere does not offer any configuration-only support for HSTS

How do i go about setting or configuring HSTS on IBM - WebSphere Application Server v7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a servlet filter and use the servlet API to set any response header you like.

Comment: It works i have added the filter on web descriptor, web.xml. Then  also implemented the response headers Filter. for example check this : https://github.com/ggrandes/headers-servlet-filter